# Building micro controller memory image in IDA

Tags: ida, memory, embedded

I have `STM32F303 Nucleo` board ([Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303vc.pdf)), and I work with Mbed IDE, which allows me to compile code to the board. The compiled code is in `.bin` format.

### Some relevant information from the datasheet:

- Cpu is Arm-v7
- Flash memory starts at `0x8000000`
- SRam starts at `0x20000000`

I want to load in IDA the `.bin` file, and map the `ROM` and `RAM` sections according to the memory map.

I tried many different configurations in the memory organization form, but couldn't find the one that represents the actual memory. The default form as IDA recognizes it:

[image]

From what I understand, the size of the `bin` file is `0x632c`, which includes both the RAM and ROM. Any ideas of how can I make the cut between the two sections? And when I do, what is the right way to fill it in the memory form?

Answer (score 1):

The *image* is for the flash so it contains only ROM. RAM is initialized by the startup code by copying some bytes from the ROM. This should work:

- ROM start and load base: 0x8000000
- RAM start: 0x20000000

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5435043